# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in OpenCLNet.dll

Tags: c#, opencl.net

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in OpenCLNet.dll

@

Platform test = new Platform(platformid);
and "platformID" has a value of 1 in runtime.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr[] IntPtrArr = new IntPtr[10];
        uint platformID;
        OpenCL.GetPlatformIDs(1, IntPtrArr,out platformID);
        IntPtr platformid = new IntPtr(platformID);
        Platform test = new Platform(platformid);
    }
}
```

Am I even getting the PlatfromID or the platfromid correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OpenCL.GetPlatformIDs` out parameter is not a platform ID, it is the amount of platforms that are set in your `IntPtrArr`, check to see the entries in `IntPtrArr` have been set, and if so use them as your `platformID`.